# javascript - hide results when input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I have Live Search JSON Data Using Ajax jQuery, and I would like to call more than one JSON file for the search.

At the start of the page, with the input empty, the results are not shown.
However, if you write and delete text again in the input, all results are displayed.

I would like to hide all the results again when the input is empty again.

Thank you in advance.

HTML Input:

```
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('1.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data.entries, function(key, value){
    if (value.title.search(expression) != -1 || value.author.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class">'+value.title+'  <span class="text-muted">'+value.author+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });
 
 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you add an if condition to check if length of input on change is > 1. ? then do your request and show div else ... remove the div

Comment: can you show me how to do this please? thank you @Zaidabukhalaf

Comment: $('#search').keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 1) {
         // Continue work
    } else {
         $('#result').html('')
    }

Comment: use .html("") method in jquery to clear the data appended ok ? @Pedro

Comment: thanks again! yes i will try i will apply here, i am still new to javascript @Zaidabukhalaf

Comment: Side note- It's not practical to make new request every time to static resource when you could request it once only and use the same promise each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#search').keypress(function() { 
if($(this).val().length > 1) { 
// Continue work 
} else { 
$('#result').html('') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `keypress` and `keydown` check the length before the text change. You can use `keyup` and `change`.

It is better to use it with `keyup`:

```
$('#txt1').keyup(function() {
    if (!$(this).val().length) $('#result').html('');
});
```

You can also use `change`:

```
$('#txt1').change(function() { 
    if (!$(this).val().length) $('#result').html('');
});
```

The change will be executed when you click somewhere else on the page.